# Does java use ArrayList or LinkedList when you only specify that you are using a List interface?

Tags: java, arraylist, linked-list

I just realized that I have some code that runs and all of the tests pass even though I never specify which specific implementation of the List interface to use.

This is the function in question

```
public List<Product> getProductList(int CategoryId)
{
    List<Product> returnedProducts = null;
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("https://www.shirts.io/api/v1/products/category/"+CategoryId+"/?api_key="+this.apiKey);
    try
    {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
        {
            entity = response.getEntity();
            jsonResponse = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

            Type listType = new TypeToken<List<Product>>(){}.getType();
            JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(jsonResponse);
            ArrayNode products = (ArrayNode) root.path("result");
            returnedProducts = (List<Product>) gson.fromJson(products.toString(), listType);
        }

    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return returnedProducts;
}
```

This is the test for the above function

```
public void testGetProductCategories()
{
    List<Category> categories = null;
    categories = productCalls.getProductCategories();
    assertEquals(20,categories.size());
}
```

Everything works fine without giving me any compilation errors. Why does this happen? I  thought you had to specify whether you were using an ArrayList or a LinkedList. Why does my code run without me having to specify one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it doesn't matter which implementation of `List` is being used by `fromJson`.  You're calling a method that returns a `List` -- it is creating some kind of `List`, but it doesn't matter which implementation it is.  If it did, then it would return an `ArrayList` or some other specific implementation.

Because it returns `List`, someone could change the implementation of the `List` returned by `fromJson`, and your code wouldn't have to change, because it's still a `List`, and that's all that's needed.

Comment: After reading some of the responses, I get that gson just returns a List and that it somehow decides which one to use. But now that I have a generic List interface aren't I going to have to use "List" through out all of my code? If I wanted to use a specific implementation I couldn't say ArrayList myList = object.getProductList().

Comment: Yes, you'll have to use `List`, but there's no problem with that.  Do you really care which implementation of `List` it is?  You can always get the runtime type with `returnedProducts.getClass().getName()` if you're curious, but it looks like `List` provides all the functionality you need here.  You could also say `new ArrayList<Product>(returnedProducts)` to convert whatever `List` is being returned into an `ArrayList` if you wanted to do that.  But again, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

As you return the result of `gson.fromJson(products.toString(), listType);`, the responsibility of creating a concrete `List` object lies at `gson`.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, `List` is an interface. The concrete [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementation (`ArrayList` or `LinkedList` or some other `List`) will be chosen by gson, and should not be important to you (as a caller). If you are curious, you can always call `getClass()` like so -

```
if (categories != null) {
  System.out.println(categories.getClass().getName());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, since `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` both implement `List`, they are both `List` instances.

Everywhere you see a reference to a `List`, it can be refering to an `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`, or any other implementation. It is called an `is an` relationship.

It is like your car, if the traffic laws talk about "your car", it refers to it whatever its brand, because a Suzuki or a Volkswagen both implement the "contract" of car.

Usually, it is good advice to use the more general interface/superclass that offers the functionality that you need. That way, you can change just the instantiation class of the object for other class also in the same `is an` relationship,  and the rest of your code will need not to change.

Comment: I get that they both implement the List interface. But I thought that you couldn't instantiate an interface and instead would have to instantiate an object of a class that implements that interface.

Comment: You don't instantiate an object from an interface, only from non-abstract classes, you are right in that. In the end, there will be a `new ClassName()`. But the reference that you get to the instance can be handled by a variable whose type is of an interface: `List myList<String> = new ArrayList<String>();`